# App Installation not saved to Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, ios9

I am currently adding push notifications to my Parse app, and need to register each device using a `PFInstallation` to do so. My app was successfully registered for push notifications, as the first time I launched it, it asked me if I wanted to receive push notifications on the device. The first time I launched, I ran the code in the appropriate `AppDelegate.m` method, as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Registered");
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

This should have saved my device to Parse using a `PFInstallation`. However, when I go to Parse.com and go to the Push tab, and look under "Audiences", no devices were registered. I assumed it may be because some of my distribution & development certificates, and my provisioning profile were out of date. So I updated these, and ran another similar piece of code to attempt to save a `PFInstallation`:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

I ran this in the `viewDidLoad` method of my app, as the AppDelegate.m method would only run once. However, there was still no `PFInstallation` anywhere to be seen in my Parse console.

Why is the `PFInstallation` not being registered? And how can I fix this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the place to look for your saved PFInstallation. Go instead to

```
Core -> Data -> Installation
```

to see if it is stored correctly in the table.

Comment: Thank you. The Installation tab wasn't originally showing, but it is now that I ran the same code in my viewDidLoad. How can I get a device's deviceToken, so that I can update the installation? This field is currently empty.

Comment: The only way I know is through the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method. You should not handle this in viewDidLoad. To get your AppDelegate to trigger again you could log out your current user and log back in.